# How can the space between a paragraph title and its body be eliminated?

Tags: sections-paragraphs

Is there a way to eliminate the space between a paragraph title and its body?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Title}and body.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can do that with`titlesec`. But, as far as I remember, the `runin` shape is the default  for `\paragraph`.

Comment: paragraph is a 4th level heading so should only be used after subsubsection you can copy the 1 line definition from article.cls and adjust the space or use a package such as titlesec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on David Carlisle's comment:

`\paragraph` is a level heading, usually used after `subsubsection`, and has a default design (to show that it is header), like the space above,  the bold font and indentation of the title,  and the larger inline space between the title an the rest of the body.

In this case we can  change the default design as you requested  with  `\renewcommand\paragraph{...` where a space separation  of `-1em`  was replaced with the original inter word space, stored in `\fontdimen2`.

There is a more exact replacement  to fully emulate the behavior of inter word space, but it is simpler to use
`\textbf{Title} and body.`, as shown in the third line of the figure.

The `titleec` package makes it easy to customize headers consistently.

[image: x]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}% space above
    {-\the\fontdimen2\font}% changed from the original -1em
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}% title font
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text before paragraph.
    
\paragraph{Title}and body.

\noindent\textbf{Title} and body.   
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the code from article class and change the 1em to 0pt

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {0pt}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Title}and body.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a proper eliminate!